# How to specify an arbitrary (possibly non-integer) font size in LaTeX

Tags: fontsize

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that I cannot obtain non-integer (or non-preloaded) font sizes (say, 9.876pt) using `\fontsize`.  If this is true, how do I do this in LaTeX?  Do I have to resort to the `\font ... at ...` primitive?

(The reason I need this is that I'd like to implement a more LaTeXy way to do the `\diminuendo` macro from http://tug.org/texshowcase/.)

Comment: This is closely related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47160/getting-a-larger-font-not-fontsize/

Comment: That's true (I didn't find that one), although it might make sense keeping this question in case someone needs it (and then he can find the link you mentioned).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can specify arbitrary non-integer font sizes using `\fontsizes` so you are mistaken ;-). But in order to work two things need to be true as well:

- the font in use needs to be available in the size you request (what that means in a minute)
- LaTeX must **know** that the font exists in the requested size.

If the first requirement is false you are out of luck and the only way to resolve things is by using scaling as suggested in [Getting a larger font (NOT \fontsize)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47160/getting-a-larger-font-not-fontsize) or a combination of `\fontsize`and scaling.

However, if it is simply the problem that LaTeX doesn't know about the available sizes then you can correct this by changing your NFSS (New Font Selection Scheme) setup.

### Example:

We use a large size 39.976pt so that we can easily spot issues:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{39.876}{42}\selectfont      Test CM

\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont                Test ppl

\showoutput
\end{document}
```

If we run this through LaTeX we will get

[image]

We can see that Computer Modern comes out much smaller than Palatino (the second font selected).

We also get a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 14.996pt have occurred.
```

which shows that at least one font was "off" by nearly 15pts (that's the CM font) and if we look at the details provided by the `\showoutput` command we see lines like

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88 T
....\kern-1.94974
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88 t
....\glue 7.51096 plus 3.89944 minus 2.59964
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88 C
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88 M
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 12.95067
...\hbox(29.04933+11.24483)x345.0, glue set 190.71533fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 T
....\kern-3.66829
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 e
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 s
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 t
....\glue 9.969 plus 5.98138 minus 2.39249
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 p
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 p
....\OT1/ppl/m/n/39.876 l
```

which shows that LaTeX has selected a font in `24.88` for Computer Modern Roman (`cmr`)
but also that it used the requested size for Palatino (`ppl`).

### Explanation

The reason for this difference in behavior is the way the two fonts have been made known to LaTeX. In case of Palatino it is a single Type 1 font and LATeX is requested to scale it to any size as needed. But in case of Computer Modern Roman, LaTeX was told that there are different real fonts for different sizes and that onely a defined set of sizes are available.

The two definitions (from the files `ot1ppl.fd` and `ot1cmr.fd`) are

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{m}{n}{<-> pplr7t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}%
     {<5><6><7><8><9><10><12>gen*cmr%
      <10.95>cmr10%
      <14.4>cmr12%
      <17.28><20.74><24.88>cmr17}{}
```

and this difference explains the different behavior.

### Resolution

In case of Computer Modern there are in fact different real fonts available specifically designed for certain font sizes and in the early days that was all you could get. Even a low-level `\font` wouldn't help in that case. True LaTeX or TeX would then assume they could use the font, but at the time of printing things would then fail.

However, nowadays most TeX installation can generate MetaFont based fonts on the fly and thus would be able to generate any intermediate font if requested.

So why is LaTex by default still using a fixed set of fonts for Metafont based fonts? The reason for LaTeX2e was mainly to avoid getting very many generated fonts just because somebody was using special `\fontsize` values. And of course backward compatibility!

But if you want to have this possibility: no problem you just need to provide the right kind of font shape definitions. Here is one possibility for CM:

```
 \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}%
     {<-6>cmr5<6-7>cmr6<7-8>cmr7<8-9>cmr8<9-10>cmr9%
      <10-12>cmr10%
      <12-17.28>cmr12%
      <17.28->cmr17}{}
```

This is now using intervals, e.g., `cmr10`is used for all fontsizes between 10pt and 12pt, etc.

In the case of Computer Modern these type of redefinitions are in fact provided by the package `fix-cm` so simply loading this package will enable all intermediate sizes.

### Documentation

You will find some good information on LaTeX's font setup in the document [LaTeX2e font selection](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) and the [LaTeX Companion 2ed](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/books.html) has a full chapter on all the details and possibilities of it.

Comment: if using the CM fonts, the `fix-cm` package fixes these scaling issues.

Comment: thanks @ArTourter - I kind of remembered that there is a package like that but didn't remember the name. updated the answer

Comment: @FrankMittelbach It's funny then, that you are listed as *first author* in the documentation of `fix-cm`.

Comment: @HenriMenke those things happen if you get older and a non-essential package was written long time ago :-)  However, in my recollection that author listing is wrong and just came about because fix-cm was initially part of fixltx2e and when split apart was getting the author list of that package I guess - maybe something to correct next round

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Concerning the "Resolution" part, more precisely when the *.fd file is modified, I don't understand why the modified copy I've created in my local texmf does not work, so non-integer points still continue being not recognised. I mean, I've copied and modified the (e.g.) ot1cmr.fd file, then refreshed (with mktexlsr utility), but it is not seen at all by texlive. Can you help me?

Comment: @Martino I never said to change the standard .df file (not even in a local tree). But the reason that it doesn't help in your case is that .fd files are only loaded once when the combination `<enc><fam>` is not yet known to the system. But CM fonts are already loaded in the format. So overwriting the declaration in the preamble or a package works but changin gjust the fd not, because the fd is never again looked at. You would need to regenerate the format for that (so next LaTeX update would do that for you) -- or use whatever your distrib needs to do for format regen.