# Need smaller than \tiny

Tags: fontsize

I use the following to reduce the size

```
{\tiny
$$
\begin{array}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

but it is still too large. How can I further reduce the size?

Comment: Thi sis covered by http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47517/how-to-specify-an-arbitrary-possibly-non-integer-font-size-in-latex

Comment: With the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) you can also resize the entire `array` via a `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` command. This would resize the contents in its entirety though (column spacing and rules, for example).

Comment: @Werner, that actually is a perfect answer for my particular problem.  I wish it was an answer so I could give it a thumbs-up.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to get an even smaller font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57673/5764)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here are two separate suggestions: Rather than reduce the font size to a point (pun intended!) where the letters become well-nigh undecipherable just to make the array fit into the available textblock, you could (i) reduce the amount of inter-column white space and (ii) get rid of most (or even all) of the vertical lines that separate the columns of the `array`. The two adjustment methods can be used simultaneously; using one doesn't preclude using the other. And, of course, they can be used in combination with a command that changes the font size (such as `\scriptsize` and `\tiny`) in effect for the `array`.

- If I read your example correctly, you have 13 text/data columns and hence 12 inter-column spaces. LaTeX uses the parameter macro `\arraycolsep` to store the value of (half of) the amount of inter-column white space for an `array` environment. The default value of this parameter in the standard document classes (such as `article`, `report`, and `book`) is a very generous `5pt`. This may be an OK value for text typeset at a font size of `10pt` to `12pt`. Importantly, though, LaTeX does *not* shrink the value of this parameter automatically if you reduce the font size of the contents of the text/data columns. Hence, your table is going to look like it contains an awful lot of whitespace if the data/text are going to be set at `5pt` (`\tiny`) or `7pt` (`\scriptsize`).

  You may therefore want to try issuing the command

  ```
  \setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
  ```

  in the preamble, for an immediate reduction of `36pt` (i.e., `0.5in`) of total array width. Nothing to sneeze at, right? Plus, you'll get a better-looking array because the intercolumn whitespace won't overwhelm the smallish data and text. With this adjustment in effect, you may find it's no longer necessary to reduce the font size to something as puny as `\tiny`.

  A related measure you could take is *eliminate* the vertical whitespace that LaTeX inserts by default in front of the first column and after the final column. To do so, set up your array with `\begin{array}{@{}|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}` or (more succinctly) as `\begin{array}{@{}|c||*{12}{c|}@{}}`: Note the addition of the two `@{}` elements. (Incidentally, assuming that the first column contains information about the contents of the other 12 columns, I'd suggest that you *left-justify* rather than center the very first column; see below for an application of this idea.)
- You may also want to consider eliminating all, or at least almost all, of the 14 vertical lines in the array. Why? First, each vertical line takes up a `0.4pt` of space (unless you or one of the packages you've loaded have changed this value). Second, while a line width of `0.4pt` may be appropriate if the contents of the text/data columns are set in font sizes of 10pt, 11pt, or 12pt, these vertical lines tend to look quite oppressive if the numbers are set in a diminutive size of `7pt` or `5pt`.

  Do ask yourself this: Do you really need all 14 vertical lines? In fact, do you need *any vertical lines at all* in order to make the array legible? If you chose to eliminate all 14 lines, by using the definition

  ```
   \begin{array}{@{}l*{12}{c}@{}}
  ```

  you'd immediately save `5.6pt` of total array width. Still nothing to sneeze at, right?

  If eliminating *all* vertical lines is too radical for your taste, do consider getting by with only the two outermost vertical lines and the one that separates the left-most column from the second column. I.e., you could set up the array as

  ```
  \begin{array}{@{}|l|*{12}{c}|@{}}
  ```

  With this setting, you'd (i) still save `4.4pt` in total array width *and* (ii) reduce the risk of overwhelming the contents of the array with all those heavy-looking lines.

Comment: While this is probably a useful reply to the asker's original problem, Google brings me here looking for ways to actually get smaller font sizes, so it would be nice if a method to do that was the accepted one.

Comment: @tsbertalan - So you downvoted this answer because a Google search -- over whose settings I have no control! -- took you here, and because you apparently expect answers to ambiguous typographic questions to be extremely narrow? Classy, really classy.

Answer (score 19):

David Carlisle already pointed to an answer showing how to specify arbitrary font sizes. As a complement, here's how to define a new font-switching command `\miniscule` that will use a font size and baseline skip reduced by 1pt each compared to `\tiny` for the class options `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`.

Note that the name `\miniscule` (but not the actual size/skip values) is taken from the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class. Also note that you have to use a scalable font like Latin Modern to correctly display a font size of 4pt.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\ifcase \@ptsize \relax% 10pt
  \newcommand{\miniscule}{\@setfontsize\miniscule{4}{5}}% \tiny: 5/6
\or% 11pt
  \newcommand{\miniscule}{\@setfontsize\miniscule{5}{6}}% \tiny: 6/7
\or% 12pt
  \newcommand{\miniscule}{\@setfontsize\miniscule{5}{6}}% \tiny: 6/7
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tiny

\lipsum[1]

\miniscule

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why the name "miniscule".

Comment: @egreg As I wrote, inspired by `memoir`.

Comment: Indeed the question was about why did Peter Wilson choose that name.

Comment: @egreg That would be a nice first question, wouldn't it? ;-) (You could even create a [tag:curious] tag for it.)

Comment: @egreg Minuscule meaning is something very little, see i.e. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/miniscule

Comment: see also [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniscule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniscule)

Comment: Hmmm, those cross-references point to a word spelled "minuscule" rather than to one spelled "miniscule"...

Comment: @Sveinung I can see that it's a spelling error. The word comes from Latin *minusculus*, which is *minus* with a diminutive suffix like in *musculus* which is "little mouse", from which the Italian "muscolo" and the English "muscle".

Comment: @egreg -- A very interesting transition from the Latin prefixes "minus" and "maius" and the related words "minusculus" and "maiusculus" (meaning, in effect, "a bit smaller" and "a bit larger") to "musculus" -- a Latin word deriving from the shape of the biceps muscle on the upper arm that, when tensed, looks like a (rather large!) "little mouse"...

Comment: @egreg: I am sorry for my typing error, but as you see from the thesaurus, `miniscule`is just a variant of `minuscule`.

Comment: @Sveinung It's not *your* spelling error. :) One only has to decide how much time is needed so that a spelling error becomes a different spelling. :)

Comment: I chose "miniscule" as I thought that it was a proper word. I knew that "minuscule" referred to a class of letters (lower case) as opposed to "majuscule" (upper case). It seems that I have invented a new word which, to me at least, conveys the sense of being small though how it might be ordered with "minute" I don't know, although it is definitely larger than "nano".