# How to get an even smaller font size than \tiny?

Tags: fontsize

I wanted to amplify the effect of specifying the font size. So I tried:

```
{\tiny\tiny Super tiny text!}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I needed suggestions to achieve the same goal.

Comment: If your main size is 12pt, `\tiny` will use a 6pt font; at main size 10pt, it would be 5pt. Under this characters are barely legible.

Comment: Also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50887/510

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty possibility for converting almost anything to a different size is to use [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\resizebox` or `\scalebox`. In your instance, if line-breaking is not a consideration, you can use

[image]

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
%...
Normal {\tiny tiny} \scalebox{.2}{supertiny}
```

The above view is zoomed to 400%. You can modify the scaling factor `.2` to whatever you're interested in.

Comment: Scaling is perhaps the best way for me. I am trying to add labels to various schematics using Tikz. Scaling will give me much smoother control on the size of the labels (esp. when the base figures of the schematics come in all shapes and sizes).

Comment: Scaling will get you small fonts, but possibly not the correct shapes. For fonts that have design sizes, 6pt scaled down to 4pt might look different (and be less legible) than a true 4pt. Computer Modern is one of these. Use `\fontsize{}{}` instead.

Comment: @Werner Why do you refer to your solution as a dirty trick? It is one of the most useful commands that I use. I was wondering if it increases the compile time or something equivalent - stuff that computer scientists are usually obsessed about.

Comment: @ShashankSawant: It's dirty because you're not using the properties (kerning/spacing) of the font anymore, as mentioned by MPi. Note the different spacing as you progress from `\normalsize` to `\small` to `\footnotesize` to `\tiny` of the same word. Also, you loose the capability of hyphenation since you box the contents. If this is of no concern, then it's not a dirty trick! :)

Answer (score 44):

The size changing commands don't have a cumulative effect, so you simply get `\tiny`. Recall that the size chosen would be 5pt if the main size for the document is 10pt. Under 5pt characters are barely legible.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

Normal {\tiny Tiny} {\fontsize{2.5}{4}\selectfont Supertiny}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the image here is magnified. Without `lmodern` or a package that chooses a scalable font you wouldn't get "supertiny", unless you load the `fix-cm` package.

Comment: I assume this sets the font size to 4pt. Not sure what the 2.5 does?

Comment: @Annan This sets the font size to 2.5pt, with a baseline skip of 4pt

Answer (score 11):

If you do not need large font sizes, too, the easiest way is to use a document class that supports an arbitrary size for the main font, such as `scrartcl`, the article class from the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\rule{2pt}{12pt}12pt\rule{2pt}{12pt} Normal 6pt {\tiny Tiny 3pt} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The height of the bars represents 12pt.

Answer (score 11):

The `memoir` class has the declaration `\miniscule` that will give you 1 point less than `\tiny`.  You'll find the details in §3.4 of the class' manual (`texdoc memman`).

You can also use the `TeX` command `\fontsize{4pt}{6pt}\selectfont` which will select a fontsize of 4pt with 6pt of leading, or whatever you wish.

(I think this doesn't work with virtual fonts, unless your system already has the sizes for those fonts installed.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Normal text.\\
{\tiny Tiny text.}\\
{\miniscule Miniscule text.}\\

{\fontsize{4}{6}\selectfont Size 4pt with leading 6pt.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Un petit jeux

`fontspec` (via truetype/opentype) allows a `Scale=` option when defining a font. (Scaling the font is different to scaling a box with the font inside it.)

So starting with a standard class `article`, scaling the font to 50%, and then using `\tiny` gives me this:

[image: small]

egreg is right: it is hardly legible.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.5]{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
\tiny abc
\end{document}
```

But, on magnification (x2562.89%), the letter shapes are perfectly formed:

[image: small magnified]

Which suggests the idea of this, scaling even further:

[image: a signed b]

which on closer inspection, zooming in, reveals itself to be:

[image: small b magnififed]

And even more (x6400%):

[image: base of b]

How far can we go? Down to Tex sp magnitudes, perhaps?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\ftsmall[Scale=0.25,Colour=red]{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
b\kern-5.5pt{\ftsmall{\tiny abc}}
\end{document}
```

But size, position and colour does not affect presence or truly hide the text, so copy-pasting it produces `babc` as expected.

In the philatelic world, magnifying-glass text on stamps is not uncommon.

Potential applications for this scaling could be for "signing" texts (and CVs?); fractal texts along paths in TikZ; stamp-production; compressing a whole lecture's worth of notes into one . on a beamer slide for later perusal by students; bottle label design; and so on.

This quantum typography also demonstrates that mathematics (the curve descriptions of the glyphs) is true at all sizes and locations.

Edited to add:

Essentially infinite.

With three layers now, at x19462% magnification:

[image: vv small]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\ftsmall[Scale=0.25,Colour=red]{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\ftvsmall[Scale=0.02,Colour=yellow]{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
b\kern-5.5pt{\ftsmall{\tiny abc}}\kern-1.33pt{\ftvsmall{\tiny abc}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What a great idea to mark documents indeed! I was wondering if you could actually "hide" some text in the dot of the "i"?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Yes, a large amount of text could go there, like lecture notes (almost wrote 'lecture motes' :) ). It will still be able to be copied, though. Practical tryouts indicate that, for finding the spot to zoom in to, a marker will be useful (Infodot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501281/how-to-hide-searchable-text-behind-a-figure-image). And, of course, the process is recursive: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501281/how-to-hide-searchable-text-behind-a-figure-image