# Increase Font Size on the fly

Tags: fontsize

I want to increase the font size for a single word. I need to be about 20% larger than the \Huge command, but I otherwise do not wish to affect font sizes within the document. Is there a simple command to accomplish this, by scaling the single word or otherwise? 
Because an MWE is always required:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\begin{document}

This is \Huge{NOT} what I had in mind.
\Huge{Because} it is your fault.

\end{document}
```

I need the word "NOT" in the example to be about 20% larger than the word "Because," so re-defining \Huge globally won't work.

Comment: `\Huge` (and friends are font switches, not macros that take an argument. As such, you should use `{\Huge <stuff>}` not `\Huge{<stuff>}`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to get an even smaller font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57673/5764) Opposite approach, but the same solution(s) hold.

Comment: The `moresize` package defines  a `\HUGE` switch.