# Why does it seem that font sizes are quantized in typography?

Tags: fontsize, latex-base

There are several points, especially when using LaTeX, that give me the feeling that the size of a font is not really a continuous quantity, but somehow quantized, i.e. can only take *some specific predefined values*.

- LaTeX has several macros like `\Large`, `\huge`, `\footnotesize`, etc. to specify the font size I want to use. This seems very reasonable, because this is some kind of recommendation and standardization of what sizes to use for what kind of task. However, it seems there is no built-in way to set the font size to some *specific value* like `13pt` without you having to specify at least some other "independent" parameter (e.g. some skip value when using `\fontsize`).
- When using the usual document classes, e.g. article, I am restricted to sizes like `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`.
- The macro `\fontsize{13pt}{10pt}` should do the trick. However, the documentation stated (and I confirmed by myself) that the value of the first argument gets rounded to the next *available* value. E.g. `16pt`, `17pt`, `18pt` and `19pt` all gave the exact same result. Why are there just a few available options here?

In my naive understanding, fonts are vector graphics, so there should be no problem in scaling them to any arbitrary value.

My best guesses for why this is the case are

1. It is not so easy. Each font size has its own specific properties and fine tuned algorithms for type setting.
2. TeX is from a time where it was not so easy to use vector graphics as careless as today. Maybe fonts where not even vector graphics back then.

I do not have much background in the theory or history of type setting. So I might have used very wrong assumptions.

---

**Note:** I completely rewrote this question after some suggestion to clarify my intentions and to sort out the several different sub questions. I did this after some answers were given. However, I made sure that the current answers still fit the question.

Comment: `\fontsize{13pt}{14pt}\selectfont`? Although that's not the optimum.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you, this is already a new information. However, the documentation I found stated that the first argument is still restricted to some specific values (I have not found these values). Also Is there some standard way to deduce the skip value (second argument) from the first argument?

Comment: It may depend on your overall font setup where the sizes may snap to quantizied sizes. This is a simple listed in the log. Then it often helps to load the `fix-cm` package, even if your using a different font. (this is assuming pdflatex, not sure if that package is needed in xelatex if lualatex)

Comment: Many fonts are designed for specific sizes. This a font designed for 6pt might not look particularly nice optically scaled to 12pt, thus the snapping to sizes i mentioned. Fix-cm does something similar to allowing the closest font size to be optically scaled to the font size required.

Comment: You're confusing two different things: one is about whether arbitrary font sizes are possible in LaTeX (they are, although scaling isn't always ideal) and the other is about why *document classes* have limited fontsize options. Since the premise of the first question is incorrect, perhaps you should refocus the question on the second question.

Comment: The documentation that you say you saw is wrong, and there is no way to determine the second value, it is your choice.

Comment: @AlanMunn You are right. I guess I have to rewrite the complete question. Is it more appropriate to write a completely new one?

Comment: It's completely fine to revise this one, especially since nobody has answered yet.  This is one of the reasons for comments, so that questions can be improved.

Comment: @M.Winter font sizes are not quantized in latex, that entirely depends on which font you use and in which sizes its available and if scaling is supported. For example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
 
\fontsize{13.8pt}{12.4pt}\selectfont test

\fontsize{3.8pt}{2.4pt}\selectfont test

\end{document}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can specify any size that you like, for example

```
\fontsize{2cm}{2in}\selectfont
```

for a 2cm font on a 2in baseline.

However some fonts (not many these days) are only available in a fixed set of sizes. By default the initial Computer Modern fonts are restricted as originally they were only available as bitmap fonts and while they could be generated at different sizes you would not want to generate arbitrary bitmaps and fill your disk.

If you put

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

at the top of the file, Computer Modern is also allowed at any size.

Most other fonts typically used with TeX are by default allowed at arbitrary sizes.

Note that most classes offer a restricted set of font sizes not because it is technically hard to load a font at another size but because for each size supported you need to specify matching font sub/super script sizes, matching vertical spaces around lists etc, and also it is good document practice to use a small consistent set of font sizes not have different sized fonts all over the document.

So in the standard classes font choices are restricted in two ways, firstly a fixed set of named sizes `\tiny`, ... `\normalsize`, ... `\huge` ...  these do not just set the font size as would happen with `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` they also set matching spaces and math fonts. A more restricted set of three size options for the class 10pt,11pt,12pt are only loosely related to choosing a font size at all, they are named after the default font size but the class options set up page size, heading choices math font setup, so they are really best thought of a *name* of an option rather than a length.

Comment: Thank you very much for this good answer! In my naiv understanding, using a bigger font was just scaling up everything. At this moment I cannot really imagine why this should not lead to aesthetically appealing results.

Comment: @M.Winter it's not just scaling for several reasons, firstly the fonts may not scale  with cm if you select a  5pt font it is not the 10pt font scaled down but a font designed to be read at that size, similarly if you look at the spaces used in the standard classes they are not scaled in exact proportion, someone actually looked at a 15pt list on the standard page sizes and decided how much space it should have,

Comment: @M.Winter It's all about the optical human interface to the font...since small things are harder to read, the font designer adjusts things to help the reader at those sizes.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328228/appearance-of-tiny-or-scriptsize-fontsize-in-latex-horizontal-stretch/ to appreciate better... `\tiny` font is easier to read than a scaled down `\normalsize` font

Comment: @M.Winter another consideration is that if you set up the math fonts for any arbitrary font size change, that each time you would have to load up to 16 math families in three sizes (text, subscript and subsubscript) and when latex was designed you would run out of memory _very_ soon if you did this for more than a few sizes.

Comment: @M.Winter when "type" was a physical thing (i.e. pieces of metal) there was no scaling - there was a set of fixed sizes, just like mechanical nuts and bolts (try buying an 11.3mm diameter bolt in your local DIY shop!) Some of the scaling issues also depend on the display or printing technology - real "ink on paper" always spreads and runs to some extent, and "computer screens" have a fixed pixel resolution. Professional fonts are designed so that at "standard" sizes, those limitation don't create annoying visual artefacts. Arbitrary scaling is too hard to do, to get the same quality output.

Answer (score 15):

> Why is it that font sizes seems to be of a quantized character instead of being continuous? This seems not to be restricted to TeX, but an overall thing in typography.

Indeed, the "quantized character" of font sizes is not restricted to TeX and friends, it's widely observed in (good) typography. Basically, when you change font sizes (say, for headers, or for footnote material), you want to make the size change both noticeable and yet "not too jarring" as well.

- For *text material*, a well-established typographic convention is to change the font sizes in a geometric progression of 20% increments/decrements. E.g., if the basic font size is `10pt`, `\footnotesize` is 20% (linearly) smaller (`8pt`), while `\large` and `\Large` are 20% and 44%, resp., linearly larger (`12pt` and `14.4pt`, resp.). And so on.
- For *math material*, the typographic convention implemented by TeX and friends is to make subscript and superscript items 30% linearly smaller, and sub-subscript and super-superscript material 30% linearly smaller yet again, for a total reduction of roughly 50% below the basic font size. (0.7 times 0.7 = 0.49.) Thus, if the basic font size is 10pt, `\scriptsize` is `7pt` and `\scriptscriptsize` is `5pt`.

Why step sizes of 20% for text material rather than, say, 22% or 18%? I trust nobody is going to claim that 20% represents the unique solution to some well-specified visual optimization problem. The step sizes were arrived at over long periods of time, through various trial and error processes. My guess is that size changes of about 10% (or less) are probably too small to be easily recognized, while sizes of about 30% (or more) are too jarring for "average" aesthetics. 20% was probably arrived at as "something that looks ok to most readers".

If you really, really believe that the step size progression ought to use 18% instead of 20%, it's actually not too much effort to achieve that. However, virtually none of your readers will take notice, while the few who do are unlikely to appreciate the effort you've put in.

---

You also asked an entirely separate question, which was about why the `article` document class offers only `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` as the main font sizes. I suppose that's a legacy of the fact that this document class and its siblings, the `report` and `book` classes, have been around since the days of LaTeX2.09 (and probably even longer). Back in the 1980s, practically the only font family available for use with LaTeX was Computer Modern, with (you guessed it) `10pt`, `11pt` (really: 10.95pt, i.e., the geometric mean between 10pt and 12pt) and `12pt` as the main text font sizes. More-recent document classes offer additional choices. For instance, the `memoir` document class offers the following default font size options: 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25, 30, 36, 48, and 60 [!] points. The KOMA-Script document classes nowadays let you specify just about any size. Not all font size choices will generate readable output, though. E.g, if you set the main document size to `3pt`, absolutely nobody will be able to read a word of what you wrote unless you also provide your readers with high-powered magnifying glasses...

Comment: The discrete steps were an obvious technical limitation with metal type.

Comment: @egreg - Indeed, if `12pt` were the main document font size and a 20% step size is deemed optimal, one should use `9.6pt` for `\footnotesize`. However, all LaTeX document classes I'm familiar with which provide a `12pt` main font size option use `10pt` rather than `9.6pt` for `\footnotesize` -- presumably because Computer Modern offers 10pt but not 9.6pt as well which, in turn, probably goes back to the limitations of metal type.

Comment: @Mico -- all the choices that knuth made were based on the traditions of metal type, and in particular, of what was available from monotype.  take a look at this paper: http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/Rhatigan_Monotype_4-line_math.pdf and also google "monotype math typesetting" for more references.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - An excellent point! For extra clarity, I should maybe have written that the Computer Modern fonts, at sizes from`5pt` to `17pt`,  were based on and influenced by metal type precursors from Monotype which, in turn, incorporated lots of typographic traditions related to font size changes.

Comment: You ask: "Why step sizes of 20% for text material rather than, say, 22% or 18%?" IA rescaling factor of 2 is very natural, but it is too much. If you want to reduce it you choose q such that q^2=2 so that applying the rescaling twice you double the size. This means q=sqrt(2)=1,41 or 41%. If this is too much you repeat again and find sqrt(sqrt(2)) = 1.19 which is 19%.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini - Moreover, in the somewhat distant past, step size calculations based on a multiplicative factor of 1.2 must be a lot easier to carry out (and almost certainly a lot less error prone) than those based on a factor of 1.1892, right? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well... I'm agree with Mico when he said your question involved two different issues: on the one hand the way fonts are scaled to generate the visual structure of a document and on the other hand the (limited) set of sizes available in the standard classes.

I will start answering to the first without relying on what has been said in previous answers and comments.

The percentages given by Mico are a sample of how a typographic scale works, in the case of `TeX`, is parameterized as a function of a single variable or parameter, which is the size of the base text, however takes into account that the proportions of the scale depend on optical considerations that vary with each typography, inasmuch as their own proportions and strokes may need slightly different adjustments, E.G. a large x height implies ascending strokes shorter than a letter with an x height smaller and that fact can make that two typographies of the same size require different adjustments to obtain the same visual result.

I understand that `TeX` and `LaTeX`, in addition, are designed in the best editorial tradition, so Donald Knuth was based on the tradition of the Monotype metal types as Barbara Beeton points out.

In this sense, it is necessary to see that good editorial design does not have a quantic or continuous approach, it is a question of making use of a congruent way of a scale that allows the size of the page, the type box and the typography chosen to harmonize each.

When, instead of using LaTeX, you make use of some DTP like Scribus, InDesign or QuarkXpress (does QuarkXpress still exist?), you need to choose the base grid around which the base body text size must fit for the reading text, and each one of the headings, the text in quotations or footnotes. You must adjust the dimensions of the typographic box so that it matches the final size of the page and that the font size is adequate to form lines of text of the necessary length and fit with the above requirements I have just outlined.

Any change in these decisions may involve a complete redesign of everything, and since this approach is `WYSIWYG`, it requires a lot of time to make all these changes, in addition to greater knowledge to achieve a result comparable to that achieved with `TeX`.

In this sense we can say that TeX is a tool rather to design parametrically, and therefore allows to make changes with a facility that people who live in the visual logic of the DTP can't even imagine.

The connection with your second question is on the scale or scales used in design, a very interesting example you can find in *[Le Modulor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulor)*.

Since `TeX` makes use of a parametric design, it is not surprising that the scale it uses is a function of a single parameter, that is, the base body of the text. In this way, by choosing that value, you can adjust the entire scale without having to worry about doing it manually as in a DTP.

I don't know what you think, but IMHO, this is wonderful and allows to obtain a professional typographic quality to any n00b who has neither the time nor the desire to delve into these details.

However, standard classes allow you a value for the base text of between 10 and 12 points, it is not a willful limitation or the product of a technical limitation almost impossible to solve, it is, again, part of a deep-rooted editorial tradition, which dictates that the base body for a book, *ranges from 10 to 12 points*, depending on the typography chosen and other considerations such as line spacing, width of typographic box, etc.

I must confess that when I saw the first comments to your question I was surprised that no one mentioned `KOMA Script`, again I thank MICO that he has finished with that omission.

Briefly, I have to say that `KOMA Script` is a bundle of packages that IMNSHO, greatly improves the capabilities of `standard classes`, corrects their errors and therefore escapes their limitations. You can choose a font size for the base text smaller than 10 pt and much greater than 12 pt retaining the scales, which you will find, I think, quite useful.

Thinking in the example given by samcarter in the comments to your question, we can get something like this:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,paper=a4,DIV=calc,BCOR=5mm]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\begin{document} 

\section{Test}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  
\end{document}
```

In a nutshell, as you can see, `TeX`, and therefore `LaTeX`, are designed according to best editorial practices, one of them is to use a 10 pt to 12 pt text size for the reading text in a document, from which all the other sizes you can use are calculated. Thus, unlike a DTP or a word processor, you forget to waste time adjusting margins and font sizes, not to mention the format inconsistencies.

Comment: @Mico I meant that these percentages may vary slightly depending on the typography chosen. I did not say it by the way `TeX` scales the letters in that percentage, but thinking of a manual adjustment of a typographic scale. In addition the variances would be small, for example, instead of 20% it was 21.02% or something like that.

Comment: @Mico Well, I didn't mean to offend or disqualify you or say you were wrong, I was rather "thinking aloud" about different typographies that because of their design required optical adjustments that might vary slightly from the values you wrote. I didn't think of Computer Modern but rather a lot of fonts that escape the proportions and design of the default font in `LaTeX`. I regret that I have hurt sensitivities and I hope this wording would be clearer. Regards.

Comment: No worries -- you neither offended me nor hurt my feelings. I was just genuinely unsure as to what you were trying to say. I like the revised paragraph -- +1. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To complement other answers. Originally TeX fonts were encoded in MetaFont. MetaFont contains a description of how glyphs and characters should be outlined. Moreover different font sizes are not simply rescaled versions of each other: small fonts can have relatively larger pen strokes or other variations to be more readable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont).

When a new font size was used, the TeX engine required the whole font to be computed (in raster form) from the metafont description. At that time this required a lot of time and a lot of disk space.