# Scale down verbatim environment even further

Tags: beamer, scaling, fancyvrb

I am using the `fancyvrb` package. Even though I set the font size to `\tiny`, it still doesn't properly fit in a single slide. I was wondering is there a way to scale it down even further. Thank you

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]{Example}{Classical attribute grammar to find semantic errors in a program}

\scalebox{.9}{
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\tiny]
program -> block
    block.env = empty_env()
    program.msgs = block.msgs
    
block -> "begin" decls stmts "end"
    decls.envin = block.env
    stmts.env = decls.envout
    decls.uin = stmts.used
    block.used = decls.uout
    block.msgs = decls.msgs ++ stmts.msgs
    
decls ->
    decls.envout = decls.envin
    decls.uout = decls.uin
    decls.msgs = { }

decls -> decls decl
  decls1.envin = decls0.envin
  decl.envin = decls1.envout
  decls0.envout = decl.envout
  decl.uin = decls0.uin
  decls1.uin = decl.uout
  decls0.uout = decls1.uout
  decls0.msgs = decls1.msgs ++ decl.msgs

decl -> id ":" type ";"
  decl.envout = add_env(<id, type.shape>, decl.envin)
  decl.uout = decl.uin - id
  decl.msgs = if id in decl.uin then
                { }
              else
                { "unused: " + id }

type -> "integer"
  type.shape = INTSHAPE

type -> "string"
  type.shape = STRSHAPE

stmt ->
  stmts.used = { }
  stmts.msgs = { }

stmts -> stmts stmt
  stmts1.env = stmts0.env
  stmt.env = stmts0.env
  stmts0.used = stmts1.used ++ stmt.used
  stmts0.msgs = stmts1.msgs ++ stmt.msgs

stmt -> block ";"
  block.env = stmt.env
  stmt.used = block.used
  stmt.msgs = block.msgs

stmts -> expr ":=" expr ";"
  expr1.env = stmt.env
  expr2.env = stmt.env
  stmt.used = expr1.used ++ expr2.used
  stmt.msgs = (if expr1.shape != expr2.shape then
                { "type mismatch" }
              else
                { }) ++ expr.msgs

expr -> INT_CONSTANT
  expr.shape = INTSHAPE
  expr.used = { }
  expr.msgs = { }

expr -> strconstant
  expr.shape = STRSHAPE
  expr.used = { }
  expr.msgs = { }

expr -> id
  local shape = lookup(id, expr.env)
  expr.shape = shape
  expr.used = { id }
  expr.msgs = if shape == NOT_FOUND then
                { id + " not declared" }
              else
                { }
\end{Verbatim}
\end{multicols}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With scale box:
[image]

Without scale box:
[image]

Comment: reconsider the content of your slide. If the text doesn't fit in tiny, you have to much text. Depending on how you present it is perhaps even not readable at all.

Comment: unrelated to beamer you can not have multicols in a scalebox

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to be able to read `\tiny` text on a slide? Rethink how you are showing stuff to your audience (maybe two slides?)

Comment: @PeterWilson Good point. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way? See: [How to get an even smaller font size than \tiny?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57673/how-to-get-an-even-smaller-font-size-than-tiny).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]{Example}{Classical attribute grammar to find semantic errors in a program}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\fontsize{2.5}{4}\selectfont]
program -> block
    block.env = empty_env()
    program.msgs = block.msgs
    
block -> "begin" decls stmts "end"
    decls.envin = block.env
    stmts.env = decls.envout
    decls.uin = stmts.used
    block.used = decls.uout
    block.msgs = decls.msgs ++ stmts.msgs
    
decls ->
    decls.envout = decls.envin
    decls.uout = decls.uin
    decls.msgs = { }

decls -> decls decl
  decls1.envin = decls0.envin
  decl.envin = decls1.envout
  decls0.envout = decl.envout
  decl.uin = decls0.uin
  decls1.uin = decl.uout
  decls0.uout = decls1.uout
  decls0.msgs = decls1.msgs ++ decl.msgs

decl -> id ":" type ";"
  decl.envout = add_env(<id, type.shape>, decl.envin)
  decl.uout = decl.uin - id
  decl.msgs = if id in decl.uin then
                { }
              else
                { "unused: " + id }

type -> "integer"
  type.shape = INTSHAPE

type -> "string"
  type.shape = STRSHAPE

stmt ->
  stmts.used = { }
  stmts.msgs = { }

stmts -> stmts stmt
  stmts1.env = stmts0.env
  stmt.env = stmts0.env
  stmts0.used = stmts1.used ++ stmt.used
  stmts0.msgs = stmts1.msgs ++ stmt.msgs

stmt -> block ";"
  block.env = stmt.env
  stmt.used = block.used
  stmt.msgs = block.msgs

stmts -> expr ":=" expr ";"
  expr1.env = stmt.env
  expr2.env = stmt.env
  stmt.used = expr1.used ++ expr2.used
  stmt.msgs = (if expr1.shape != expr2.shape then
                { "type mismatch" }
              else
                { }) ++ expr.msgs

expr -> INT_CONSTANT
  expr.shape = INTSHAPE
  expr.used = { }
  expr.msgs = { }

expr -> strconstant
  expr.shape = STRSHAPE
  expr.used = { }
  expr.msgs = { }

expr -> id
  local shape = lookup(id, expr.env)
  expr.shape = shape
  expr.used = { id }
  expr.msgs = if shape == NOT_FOUND then
                { id + " not declared" }
              else
                { }
\end{Verbatim}
\end{multicols}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]