# How smaller can we go in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, zooming

I want to visualise a Big TikZ figure and I need to have very small font for it to fit into the picture. 1000-10000 times smaller than \tiny command how do I go about doing this if that's even possible ?
Thanks for any hints.

Here is a rough idea of what the figure I am looking to fit into a single page, keep in mind that I'm looking for 100000 lines instead of a dozen as shown below:

```
\begin{document}


\newpage

\[\begin{tikzcd}
\bullet&\\
\bullet&&&\bullet&\\
\bullet&&&\bullet&&\\
&&\bullet&&\bullet&&&\\
\bullet&&\bullet&&\bullet&&&&\bullet&&\\
&&&\bullet&&\bullet&&&&&\\
\bullet&&&&\bullet&&\bullet &&&&&\bullet&&\\
&&&\bullet&&&&&&&&\bullet&&\bullet&&&\\
&&&\bullet&&&&&&\bullet&&\bullet&&&&&&\bullet&&\\
&\bullet&&&&&&\bullet&&&\bullet&&&&\\
\bullet&&\bullet&&&&\bullet&&\bullet&&&&\bullet&&&&&&&&\\ 
\end{tikzcd}\]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a normal font and make the page/tikzpicture larger?

Comment: `\fontsize{1pt}{1.5pt}\selectfont`  or use the scale options in tikz

Comment: 1000 times smaller? Are you serious? We're talking about micrometres...

Comment: David Carlisle, I want to go even smaller than that.  To give an idea I want the font size to be \fontsize{0.0001pt}{0.0015pt}

Comment: Yes, It's a very large picture. Essentially each line contains 10000+ $\bullet$

Comment: I'm curious to see what image could be so huge.

Comment: How do you plan to view your document? Most pdf viewers have a fixed range how far the allow to zoom in/out.

Comment: https://t.ly/UnMuH This is only the beginning of the graph and it already difficult to zoom out

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: Is your whole figure just dots or do you also have actual text?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It's just dots

Comment: You could draw them as circles instead. This way you can control their size much easier than changing the font size.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Can you please elaborate further, it would be very helpful if you could provide an example with just one circle.  Thanks

Comment: you can have that font size if you want (as long as no one ever needs to read it)

Comment: @HomerSimpson Given that your question does not contain a test document, I'd rather not create a new document from scratch.

Comment: Essentially what I want to see when zooming out is to confirm a conjecture about the alignment of the dots. so I presume than when zooming out I can see the pattern emerge more clearly.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, would you like me to provide you with one ? I'll do so right away

Comment: @HomerSimpson Yes, please

Comment: From the comments it is pretty clear this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You seem to want to draw some array of dots. And you are representing the array using Tikz-CD (best that I can tell), and using $\bullet$ for each dot. But for your use case almost certainly just representing your visualization as a [bitmap image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) would be better and easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @WillieWong, you're actually right. I am somewhat aware that this is an XY problem, but before taking a step back and trying a whole new approach, I need to see that the numerical data matches what's conjectured. I hope you understand.

Comment: @HomerSimpson If you have this as numerical data, use a plotting tool like pgfplots and don't do this by hand! For your amount of data maybe something R, [root](https://root.cern.ch/) or matplotlib would be better suited

Comment: The pict2e package should support `\circle*{1sp}`, although I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: If you are aware this is an XY problem, the solution is to tell us about the X and Y, not tell us the X and begin a 20 comment thread while we give you different options for Y.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to get an even smaller font size than `\tiny`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57673/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using tikz-cd and `\bullet` to draw circles seems a rather complicate approach. You could directly use TikZ to draw circles wherever and in whatever size you want (as long as you stay within the numerical limits of TikZ):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[red, radius=0.1]
\fill (0,0) circle;
\fill (0,2) circle;
\fill (0,3) circle;
\fill (0,4) circle;
\fill (2,3.5) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for fun: Here, the smallest radius at which the PDF viewer still shows me something at a magnification of 10000% is 500sp. ;-)