# How to get larger fonts than \Huge in nodes with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, nodes

I need to write large fonts which are included in nodes of a tikzpicture. When I change scale, everything changes but not fonts. Here´s my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]

\path [fill=red] (0cm,1.5576cm)--(0cm,.6227cm).. controls (.05cm,.28cm) and (.25cm,.17cm) ..(.6512cm,0cm)--(.6512cm,.9076cm) .. controls (.4cm,1cm)and(.1cm,1.1cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\path [fill=red](0cm,1.5576cm).. controls (.12cm,1.2cm)and(.45cm,1.1cm)..(.8118cm,.9918cm)--(.8118cm,.0931cm)--(.9764cm,.2014cm)--(.9764cm,1.0681cm) .. controls (.45cm,1.12cm)and(.15cm,1.31cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\path [fill=red](0cm,1.5576cm).. controls (.2cm,1.32cm)and(.7cm,1.21cm)..(1.141cm,1.1644cm)--(1.141cm,.3418cm) .. controls (1.2781cm,.4793cm).. (1.3016cm,.6227cm)--(1.3016cm,1.2727cm) .. controls (.7cm,1.3cm)and(.2cm,1.4cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\path [fill=red] (0cm,1.5576cm).. controls (.2cm,1.47cm)and(.7cm,1.3cm)..(1.3016cm,1.4212cm)--(1.3016cm,1.5576cm) .. controls (.7cm,1.42cm)and(.2cm,1.49cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\draw (2,1.5) node {\fontsize{52}{58}\sffamily\bfseries TEXT};

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `scale=5` option to your node.

Comment: Fonts are also resizeable using `\resizebox{!}{20cm}{\sffamily\bfseries text}` with [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: Load the `fix-cm` package or load the `lmodern` fonts instead.

Comment: @percuße It doesn't work, I've just change the code to depict.

Comment: It should be supplied to the node not the tikzpicture environment such as `\node[scale=5] {\Huge Text};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you load a font that will scale properly, then your example will work without scaling. If you want to use the standard Computer Modern, then load the `fix-cm` package. Otherwise, load the `lmodern` package. Scaling on the picture specifically doesn't apply to node text in TikZ by default.

As noted in the comments, it's better style to put the font parameters as part of the `font` key of the node rather than directly inside the node itself.

See [How to specify an arbitrary (possibly non-integer) font size in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47517/2693) for more information on font sizes.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [fill=red] (0cm,1.5576cm)--(0cm,.6227cm).. controls (.05cm,.28cm) and
   (.25cm,.17cm) ..(.6512cm,0cm)--(.6512cm,.9076cm) .. controls
   (.4cm,1cm)and(.1cm,1.1cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\path [fill=red](0cm,1.5576cm).. controls (.12cm,1.2cm)and(.45cm,1.1cm)..
   (.8118cm,.9918cm)--(.8118cm,.0931cm)--(.9764cm,.2014cm)--(.9764cm,1.0681cm) ..
   controls (.45cm,1.12cm)and(.15cm,1.31cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\path [fill=red](0cm,1.5576cm).. controls (.2cm,1.32cm)and(.7cm,1.21cm)..
   (1.141cm,1.1644cm)--(1.141cm,.3418cm) .. controls (1.2781cm,.4793cm)..
   (1.3016cm,.6227cm)--(1.3016cm,1.2727cm) .. controls (.7cm,1.3cm)and(.2cm,1.4cm)..
   (0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\path [fill=red] (0cm,1.5576cm).. controls (.2cm,1.47cm)and(.7cm,1.3cm)..
   (1.3016cm,1.4212cm)--(1.3016cm,1.5576cm) .. controls
   (.7cm,1.42cm)and(.2cm,1.49cm)..(0cm,1.5576cm)--cycle;

\draw (2,1.5) node[font=\fontsize{52}{58}\sffamily\bfseries]{TEXT};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]