# How to get math font larger than Huge in node？

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, nodes, text

I need to add text to a pdf, but the largest \Huge is not big enough, so I change the font size according to [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96566/how-to-get-larger-fonts-than-huge-in-nodes-with-tikz)'s answer, but I found that this command does not work for math fonts. You can see that only the text is successful. , and I need a command that works on mathematical symbols

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw=none,fill=none] at (0,0){\includegraphics{one-inc.pdf}};
    \node[font=\fontsize{80}{200}\selectfont] at (25cm,3.5cm) {K};%
    \node[font=\fontsize{80}{200}\selectfont] at (24cm,3.5cm) {$K_x$};%
    \node[font=\fontsize{80}{200}\selectfont] at (23cm,3.5cm) {$\omega$};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: node1]

what should I do

Comment: you are asking about math fonts so don't make an example that does `\includegraphics{one-inc.pdf}` so that no one can run the example.

Comment: The second argument in `\fontsize{80}{200}` seems needlessly large. Do consider using `\fontsize{80}{96}`. (It's common to set the second argument of `\fontsize` about 20% larger than the first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more reasonable example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{80}{200}\selectfont

K $K_x$

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

with lualatex and

[image]

with pdflatex.

In both cases giving multiple warnings such as

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <55.99976> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 7.
```

Use any font family other than computer modern math, or for cm, add the `fix-cm` package to allow arbitrary sizes.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{80}{200}\selectfont

K $K_x$

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

in lualatex

[image]

in pdflatex