# set fontsize for TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I have made many figures with tikz and want to include them in a template. Unfortunately I used `ex` as a measure and the template I have to use redefines the font size. THis leads to wrong distances in the figures. is there a way to set the font size for all tikz figures in a document, so I do not have to adjust my figures?

Comment: You could use `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]`. (Or whatever size you need.)

Comment: @CountZero: the problem is not with the text size but with mixing e.g. `\draw (3,3) -- (2ex,0);` (its not mixed that directly but i place some nodes at e.g. `(0,0)` add text above and want to draw a line above that. since I did quite a lot, I dont want to adjust the figures, I would rather to do something like `renewenviornment{tikzpicture}{\setFontSizeMagically\begin{tikzpicture}}{\end{tikzpicture}}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can enforce a font command at the start of each picture which would make the fontsize consistent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font issue=\footnotesize},
         font issue/.style={execute at begin picture={#1\selectfont}}
        }


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0) -- (10ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}A

\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0) -- (10ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}A

\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0) -- (10ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}A


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I enter arbitrary values i.e. `10pt`?

Comment: Well arbitrary is not possible in TeX if the fonts do not support but I think you are aware of it, so you can use `font issue={\fontsize{10}{12}}` above.

Comment: thanks a lot, works like a charm. For thosw hwo are unaware as I was about selecting arbitrary font sizes, [this awnser](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47539/19326) is a good read.