# How to create tikz figures via knitr forcing labels featuring LaTeX's font size modifier-commands?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, r, knitr

Is there a way to force knitr to create tikz code which includes font size information? The output would be something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
```

Here is some more background information:

I am currently writing my PhD thesis which is depending on multiple tools (e.g., R, Matlab). In order to document my work as dynamically as possible, I am using knitr for the parts which depend on R. However, I prefer to write most parts of my thesis using TeXstudio. Thus, in order to include the knited R-code in LaTeX I follow this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529833/is-there-a-way-to-include-knitr-documents-in-a-latex-document): I set up a main Rnw-file in which I include child documents. After compiling and kniting the children I put the generated tex-files in the LaTeX files (via `input{}`).

In principal this approach works fine. However, I can not figure an elegant way of how to set the font size of the nodes and labels to a specific value which is defined through **font size modifier-commands**.

So far, I fiddled around with the chunk options `size` and `dev.args=list(pointsize=[])`. While the first apparently only applies to "real" text and not to text within plots, the second does not set something like `font=\footnotesize}`. Thus, changes to the `pointsize` argument do not affect the final appearance of text in figures as the tikz files are eventually compiled with LaTeX (or LuaLaTeX to be precise).

Here is an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122257/75546) to a similar question which would be neither easily applicable in my case nor did I get it to work for me so far.

One solution I could think of would be to define global tikz styles using `\tikzstyle`. However, this at least discussed for being bad practice (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52379/75546)). Further more, how could I define it for a section in which it would apply also for tex-files that have been included via `input{}`?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the font portion of the first answer in this question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169354/best-practice-for-nice-layout-with-tikzdevice

Comment: Well, I know this answer as well. But it does not solve my problem. His suggestion is to work via `dev.args=list(pointsize=[])` which does not work in my case.