# What font size modifiers are available in LaTeX?

Tags: fontsize

What font size modifiers are available in LaTeX?

eg: `\footnotesize`, `\tiny`, `\big`, `\large`, `\huge`

It would be useful to have an exhaustive list.

Comment: Related: [What is the default font size of a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155896/5764)

Comment: Related: [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Comment: This is documented in the `LaTeX Help Book`.

Comment: different document classes have different settings; the ams classes have a more nuanced set, for example, than the basic classes.  (and this is not documented except in the ams classes themselves, as far as i am aware.)

Comment: For the basics of LaTeX, print the  [LaTeX 2ε Cheat Sheet](https://wch.github.io/latexsheet/latexsheet.pdf) and stick it in the right frame of your monitor.

Comment: @Fran although like any cheat sheet it's only an approximation to the full story, particularly for this question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree, but the full story is too much for a comment `:)` and even for a answer.  Probably a a full story should mention also your `scalefnt` package, and  `moresize` that supply `\HUGE` and `\ssmall`, `relsize` and may be some others.

Comment: Among these some others, of course,  `anyfontsize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exhaustive list is: (for the Article document type)

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

Or at least these are all I could find. Hopefully someone will edit this answer if this list ever changes.

See also: [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc).

Comment: See also [Fonts larger than `\Huge`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265/5764)

Comment: These are just the default/typical declarations that are available. There are infinitely many options, technically. A more general approach would be to use `\fontsize` - see [How to specify an arbitrary (possibly non-integer) font size in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47517/5764).

Comment: You need to specify the context for which this is an "exhaustive list". For example the `memoir` class contains two more, `\miniscule` and `\HUGE`.

Comment: @alephzero I did not know that thanks for the info

Answer (score 7):

By default, in the format there are no such commands, just a generic

```
\fontsize{xx}{yy}
```

where xx is an arbitrary length for the font size, and yy is an arbitrary length for the matching baselineskip.

A class or package may, but need not, define commands for specific sizes.

The standard article/report/book class for example define at 10pt:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\newcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt}
\newcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18}}
\newcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22}}
\newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
\newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}
```