# What is the second value in \fontsize for?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I know that it is possible to change the size of the font of the section titles in a document using `\usepackage{sectsty}` and the command `\sectionfont`; for example, to set the section titles' font to 14pt, I would use

```
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont}
```

But what does the second number (15) stand for? Nothing seems to change when I modify this value.

Comment: The `15` is the `\baselineskip` in points. The real distance is computed by the product of `\baselineskip` and `\baselinestretch`

Comment: generally it's better to use one of the defined sizes such as `\large` (and then if necessary define `\large` to be `\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont` that way you get consistend fonts across the document structures. Note that this is `\fontsize` syntax, unrelated to `\sectionfont`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The two arguments for `\fontsize{<size>}{<bskip>}` sets respectively the font size and the baseline skip. After setting, you have to `\selectfont` for the parameters to become active, making them available in `\f@size` and `\f@baselineskip`.

Some considerations:

- Not all font sizes are available, so your choice for `<size>` should be made to avoid font substitution, or choose a package that provides support for your font choice (like [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm)).
- The choice of font size and baseline skip is usually paired to avoid descenders/ascenders from sticking into the line below/above it. As such, it is advised to use the predefined or [default font switches](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155896/5764). Another motivation for using these is that they vary depending on the default document font size selected. That is, `\large` (say) has a different font size under `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` document class option.

Some examples highlighting the effect of the second argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764
{\tiny tiny\par}% 5pt font / 6pt baseline skip
{\scriptsize scriptsize\par}% 7pt font / 8pt baseline skip
{\footnotesize footnotesize\par}% 8pt font / 9.5pt baseline skip
{\small small\par}% 9pt font / 11pt baseline skip
{\normalsize normalsize\par}% 10pt font / 12pt baseline skip
{\large large\par}% 12pt font / 14pt baseline skip
{\Large Large\par}% 14pt font / 18pt baseline skip
{\LARGE LARGE\par}% 17pt font / 22pt baseline skip
{\huge huge\par}% 20pt font / 25pt baseline skip
{\Huge Huge\par}% 25pt font / 30pt baseline skip

\clearpage

{\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont \lipsum[2]\par}

{\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont \lipsum[2]\par}

{\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont \lipsum[2]\par}

\end{document}
```

The default font switches provide a good balance between font size and baseline skip to make the font readable:

[image]

Too small a baseline skip value makes the text look bunched together:

[image]

Related: [What font size modifiers are available in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264038/5764)