# how to change the font type and size?

Tags: chapters, fontsize, line-spacing, thesis

I'm new to latex and I'm trying to change the font type and size of the thesis title, chapter headings, sub chapters headings, abstract, table of figures and acknowledgment , first I tried to change the chapter headings using :

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]   {\fontsize{14}\selectfont\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter~}{0pt}{\fontsize{14}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0}{0}{0}
```

in order to respect the following table :
[image]

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do? What wasn’t working?

Comment: Also be aware that a “point” in LaTeX is a different size than a “point” in Word, so be sure you know which size you want.

Comment: @Davislor I'm trying to change the size and style of chapters first , problem that I faced is that with using 14 pt it doesn't show like its 14pt , and there is one line space only between the chapter name  and the text , I was expecting 2 lines .

Comment: Are you loading `titlesec`?

Comment: @Davislor yes I am

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted the second argument of `\fontsize{}{}` and forgot to indicate the unit of measure inside `\titlespacing*`. Using `\bfseries` you can omit `\selectfont`. Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {12pt}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3ex}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{Titolo}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: About {\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries} , 16 stands for what exactly ? because the chapter headings should be written in 14pt

Comment: 16 is the `\baselineskip`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/322256/231952

Comment: I tried the code , but the abstract and acknowledgment are not centralized , for other chapters it shouldnt be .

Comment: I can not understand what you are saying. How do you typeset the acknowledgments? And what about the "other chapters"?