# numeric font size in tikz matrix or macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

in tikz matrix i'm trying to set `row height` relatively to the font size, but for that i need to set it as a numeric value instead of names like `\normalsize` `\large`... So i use `\fontsize`, but so far i've only been able to use it through a macro as i need to first, `\setlength{\x}{#1}` where `\x is used like this` \fontsize{\x}{\x}. But in `\matrix ...` how to run `\setlength{\x}{#1}` before font=\fontsize{...}{...}? my mwe is...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,matrix anchor=north,
                    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth},
  texttable/.style 2 args={nodes={anchor=center,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt,
        text width=#1,text depth=.5ex,text height=#2, font=\fontsize{#2}{#2}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix at (0,0) [allmatrix,texttable={60mm}{10pt}] (t1) {
firt line\\
second line\\
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the macro to be able to use \fontsize is (out of tikz) ...

```
\newlength\x
\newcommand{\setnumfon}[1]{\setlength\x{#1}\fontsize{\x}{\x}\selectfont}
```

i don't how to run \setlength in a tikz macro before setting font=\fontsize{\x}{\x}

EDIT: normally we set `minimum height=` and not `text height` in tikz matrix. That allows automatic row height adjustment, but actually it also has significant text alignment problem across columns. I have once posted something on this issue, and provided my own solution using `text height` and `text depth`. This misalignment is not seen at all in tabular environment with all default settings.

Comment: Intention of your question is unclear. What you like to achieve?

Comment: I don't think your code would compile anyway: `texttable/.style 2 ags`, you meant `2 args`? And the question is quite unclear. You seem to need to transform font names in numbers but nowhere it appears in your code, since you send `10pt` to your `texttable` macro. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment:

- what you like achieve with your code?
- font size is defined by option of document class (for `article` 10, 11, and 12 pt)
- those size you can (locally) change by commands `\Huge`, `\huge`, ... `\scriptsize` and `\tiny`
- If if those commands don't give you what youafter, you can use macro `\fontsize{<size>}{<skip>}\selectfont` , where `skip` is usual about 20% bigger than `size` (it define text line spacing, see [what is `skip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322256/what-is-the-second-value-in-fontsize-for)). For example, defsault values in article is `\fontsize{10}{12}`selectfont`
- it is not clear, why you need two styles for defining style of a matrix?

**Edit:**
Regarding defining row height to size of used font: this is done automatically. So it is not clear, what is your problem.

Simplified code which works and gives (to my opinion nice result) is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
 M/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{% M as Matrix
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        nodes = {draw, anchor=center,
                 outer sep=0pt, inner sep=3pt,
                 text width=#1, text depth=0.25ex,
                 font=\fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont,
                 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth},
        matrix anchor=north,
                        }
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
\matrix at (0,0) [M=22mm/10/12] (t1)
{
first line\\
second q line\\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you not like drawn nodes border, delete option `draw` from nodes options.

If for some reason you persist to hye two styles for defining your matrix style, than you can try, if the following suggestion work for you:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
 M/.style = {% M as Matrix
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
                 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        matrix anchor=north,
                        },
Mn/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{% Mn as Matrix nodes
        nodes = {anchor=center,
                 outer sep=0pt, inner sep=3pt,
                 text width=#1, text depth=0.25ex,
                 font=\fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont}
                            }
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
\matrix at (0,0) [M, Mn=22mm/10/12] (t1)
{
first line\\
second q line\\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the both cases the compilation result is the same!

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
 M/.style = {% M as Matrix
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
                 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        matrix anchor=north,
                        },
Mn/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{% Mn as Matrix nodes
        nodes = {anchor=center,
                 outer sep=0pt, inner sep=3pt,
                 text width=#1, text height=#3,
                 text depth=0.25ex,
                 font=\fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont}
                            }
        }
```

However, if you will

Comment: As i clearly mentioned in my post initially, i.e. even before editing it, I'd like to set "text height" (awkwardly i have written `row height`) relatively to the font size. And the code shows it well; `text height=#2 ... font=\fontsize{#2}{#2}` If that works I will add factors to make it look correct.