# Formatting problems headings (TOC and document) - line spacing and spacing numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, line-spacing

I have to admit that I am a little bit desperate now, since I have been working the entire day on the following issues and was not able to come up with a proper solution.

1. I would like to have the chapters in roman numbering the rest should
   be in arabic.  Unfortunately, the roman numbering is then too close
   to the heading in the ToC. (see III. and IV).
2. In addition, I cannot set the line spacing in the headings (if they
   have two or more lines) to single line spacing. (see I.3 in the ToC
   and in the document).
3. The subparagraph is unfortunately too far to the right and I don't
   know how to move it to the far left.

It would be great if anyone of you could help me, please.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    bibliography=totoc,
    toc=listof,
    headings=small,
    listof=entryprefix,
    ]
    {scrbook}


%%% === PAKETE  === %%%
%% --- Allgemein --- %%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                         
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[]{setspace}                                                         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                            
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                     
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       
\usepackage{microtype}                                                              
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,format=hang,justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                                    
\usepackage{scrhack}


%% --- Zitieren / Fußnoten --- %%
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes,threshold=1]{csquotes}              

\usepackage[language=autobib,
    backend=biber,                                                      % switch off if MWE is not working
    citetracker=true,
    autolang=other,                                                     
    style=authoryear-comp,                                              
    maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,                                      
    uniquename=false,uniquelist=true,                                   
    isbn=false,doi=false,                                               
    dashed=false
    ]{biblatex}


% Fußnoten fortlaufend
    \usepackage{chngcntr}
    \counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
    \usepackage{bigfoot}

    

% === Allgemein === %%
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
    % Überschriften Tabellen / Abbildungen kleiner
    \captionsetup{font={small},justification=raggedright}   
    

%% === Verzeichnisse === %%

% -- Inhaltsverzeichnis -- %
    
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

%% --- Überschriften --- %%                                         
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}                     
    \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}        
    \renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
    \renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\RaggedRight}

%% --- Abstände --- %%
    % Abstand zwischen Absätzen %
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip} 
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
    
    
%% --- Schusterjungen / Hurenkinder 
    \usepackage[defaultlines=3, all]{nowidow}


    % Arabisch/Römisch Nummerierung
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

    
    % 5. Gliederungsebene
    \newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}}
    \RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=.0\baselineskip,afterskip=.0\baselineskip]{chapter}
    \RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.1\baselineskip]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
    \RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.1\baselineskip]{subparagraph}
    
    %%% Größenanpassung Überschriften
    \addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{paragraph}{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont}





%*************************************************************************************

\begin{document}

        
%%% ----- VERZEICHNISSE ----- %%%
\pagenumbering{Roman}


\tableofcontents
        
                
\cleardoublepage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing 

%*************************************************************************************


\chapter{This is chapter number 1}
    \section{This is a new section}
    \section{This is an other one}
    \section{This is an other one, but the line spacing is very long and therefore looks strange. Any ideas how to fix this? (see page 1)}
        \subsection{Subsection}
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
            \paragraph{Paragraph}
            \subparagraph{Subparagraph}

\chapter{This is chapter number 2}
\chapter{This is chapter number 3}
\chapter{This is chapter number 4}
\chapter{This is chapter number 5}
enter image description here
%*************************************************************************************
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the usual font switches to set headings font size

```tex
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{section}{\large}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\large}
\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\large}
```

in place of `\fontsize` (the second argument of `\fontsize` set [the baseline skip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/322260/316068), you can also use a smaller value). This would solve your issue #2.

For the table of content, as you have many levels, maybe the KOMA-Script `flat` style is more appropriate. You can set it with:

```tex
\KOMAoptions{toc=flat}
```

If you prefer keeping the `default` style, you can enlarge the `numwidth` for the chapter (issue #1):

```tex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocnumwidth=2em]{chapter}
```

and reduce the indent for the other levels (issue #3):

```tex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocindent=1em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocindent=2em]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocindent=3em]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocindent=4em]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocindent=5em]{subparagraph}
```

Comment: I thank you 100 times for your answer. On thing I do not understand is how I can set the baselineskip properly? Lets say it need 2em between the lines ... How can I do it?

Comment: @TRJW Set it with `\setlength{\baselineskip}{2em}`, or enlarge it with `\addtolength{\baselineskip}{2em}`. For double or one half spacing, it's best to use the package [setspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/834/316068).

Comment: Thx @jlab. Maybe you could also help me with one last topic. Is there a way to control the linespacing in the header? If the chapter/ section title is too long there are then two lines at the very top and the line spacing is rather big ....

Comment: @TRJW When you set `\fontsize{12}{17}` for sections with `\addkomafont` you set the font size to `12pt` and the baselineskip to `17pt`. Use the values you want, or add `\addtolength{\baselineskip}{-2pt}` after `\large` in `\addkomafont`. But in my humble opinion the defaults are fine.