# Non-integer fontsizes for amsart? Why is TeX still approximating to integers?

Tags: fonts, amsart

I tried, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47517/how-to-specify-an-arbitrary-possibly-non-integer-font-size-in-latex), to produce non-integer sizes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Non-integer size fonts for amsart}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \fontsize{10.6}{13.4}\selectfont  
\blindtext[1]

 \fontsize{11.4}{13.4}\selectfont  
\blindtext[1] 

%  \fontsize{11.5}{13.4}\selectfont  
%\blindtext[1]

 % \fontsize{12}{13.4}\selectfont  
 %\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

But whether I set 10.6 or 11.4 the result is the same. How can I really set a non-integer font? 
[image]

Comment: use `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` as first line or choose naturally scalable fonts eg `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: Quoting the answer: “In the case of Computer Modern these type of redefinitions are in fact provided by the package `fix-cm` so simply loading this package will enable all intermediate sizes.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `log` file:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <11.4> not available
> (Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 10.
> ```

Frank already explains the reason for this warning in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47539/9057) to the question you have linked in your question. He also tells how to solve it, e.g., using `fix-cm`. You can also use another font, e.g., Latin Modern (very similar to Computer modern) to have a scalable font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Non-integer size fonts for amsart}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\fontsize{10.6}{13.4}\selectfont  
\blindtext[1]

\fontsize{11.4}{13.4}\selectfont  
\blindtext[1] 

\fontsize{11.5}{13.4}\selectfont  
\blindtext[1]

\fontsize{12}{13.4}\selectfont  
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: several font sizes]