# Package for game/playing cards (not only poker)

Tags: positioning, boxes, double-sided

Is there a package to design playing cards (NOT ONLY POKER and similar card games, but board games like [this](http://www.rozmiarek.info/games/reviews/BangCards1.jpg) and [that](http://img.4plebs.org/boards/tg/image/1375/67/1375678990416.jpg)) in `TeX` (and friends)?

[image]

I'm well aware of [this one and a half years old topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/creating-playing-cards-using-tikz) on drawing cards using TikZ. Almost everything can be drawn in TikZ but I look for functionality to support card design and printing.

Some examples of funcionality I'd love to have:

- set card size and corner roundedness
- set paper size independentently
- automatic or semi-automatic layout (placement of cards on a page) based on margins
- twoside mode with automatic positioning of card backs
- ways to define "card templates" (for multiple types of cards in one project)
- optional dim bordering to help the workphases after printing

I know it can be done using LaTeX, but I hope there is a package to do this for me.

Update: I've found [poker.sty](http://encke.net/UpDownload-req-viewdownloaddetails-lid-23-title-poker.sty...LaTeX.Poker.package.v0.81a.html) but sadly it seems to be limited to "Poker cards" (I don't know what's the proper name for that). For cards like [this](http://www.rozmiarek.info/games/reviews/BangCards1.jpg) or [this](http://img.4plebs.org/boards/tg/image/1375/67/1375678990416.jpg) it's almost useless.

Comment: [poker.sty](http://www.encke.net/UpDownload-req-viewdownloaddetails-lid-21-title-poker.sty...LaTeX.Poker.package.v0.8a.html) seems to work for "poker cards." It might be of use for anyone only interested in those types of cards. I'm not sure if it can be made to work for more general cards as well.

Comment: your points (1), (2), (3) and (5) can be done with TikZ. (4) _I_ don't know yet, but definitively yes. For (6) I need a more detailed explanation, best with a picture.

Comment: @TomBombadil That was my conclusion too, I'm working on it. I will construct some good examples, and edit my question sometime.

Comment: Package [`labels`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/labels) allows for printing labels, badges and business cards, this might help for the page alignment

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the [documentation of poker.sty](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/poker-doc.pdf), you find that it can generate a full deck of cards. You can download the package [here](http://encke.net/UpDownload-req-viewdownloaddetails-lid-23-title-poker.sty...LaTeX.Poker.package.v0.81a.html).

You can easily modify this style to display other info on the cards, the style file is pretty straight forward.

Another option might be [this style code.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48061/creating-playing-cards-using-tikz-part-2)

I would suggest you choose either of the two and get back to us with specific questions (round corners etc) when you are modifying the templates : )

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't meant for that purpose, I guess you might find a workaround using the `baposter.cls`. It has nice options for drawing frames, aligning boxes, etc.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149620/)?