# print double sided playing cards

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, double-sided

My apologies if this is already answered somewhere (typical opening I suppose) but here goes. I've modified code from the thread [Creating playing cards using Ti*k*Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/creating-playing-cards-using-tikz) for the purposes of my needs.  Now what I am attempting to do is

1. put a 'back' on the card so when I print on cardstock the front and the back of the card lines up correctly: aka double sided
2. put more than a single card on a single page.

I've been at this for two long and finally broke down to ask the question. The code below generates the face of the card. I'd like to repeat the same face on the back side of the card where I am able to change formats, styles, images, node locations, etc., and basically just have a back to the card with same dimensions and aligns properly with the correct card.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usepackage{pifont}
 \usepackage{fourier-orns}


 \definecolor{titlebg}{rgb}{30, 30 , 30}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\icon}{$\alpha$}
    \newcommand{\cardtype}{cardtype}
    \newcommand{\cardtitle}{cardtitle}
    \newcommand{\cost}{cost}
    \newcommand{\flavortext}{flavortext}
    \newcommand{\cardcontent}{cardcontent}
    \newcommand{\cardid}{cardid}
    \newcommand{\cardimg}{img/test.jpg}


 %   TikZ/PGF Settings für die Karten
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\cardwidth}{6pt}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\cardheight}{9pt}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\imagewidth}{\cardwidth*.9}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\imageheight}{0.75*\cardheight}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\stripwidth}{0.7pt}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\strippadding}{0.2pt}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\textpadding}{0.1pt}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\titley}{\cardheight-\strippadding-1.5*\textpadding-0.5*\stripwidth}


 %   Formen der einzelnen Kartenelemente/-bestandteile
 \def\shapeCard{(0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth, \cardheight)}
  \def\shapeLeftStripLong{(\strippadding,-0.2) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding-\strippadding-1)}
 \def\shapeLeftStripShort{(\strippadding,\cardheight-\strippadding-1) rectangle (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight+0.2)}
 \def\shapeRightStripShort{(\cardwidth-\stripwidth-\strippadding,\cardheight-\strippadding-1) rectangle (\cardwidth-\strippadding,\cardheight+0.2)}
 \def\shapeTitleArea{(2*\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding) rectangle (\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth,\cardheight-2*\stripwidth)}
 \def\shapeContentArea{(2*\strippadding+\stripwidth,0.5*\cardheight) rectangle (\cardwidth+0.2,-0.2)}


 \tikzstyle{cardcorners}=[rounded corners=0.25cm]

   \begin{tikzpicture}

%debug grid and point locations
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=black!100, very thick](0, 0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = east]{ origin};
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width};
    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width, card height};
    \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=red!100, very thick](0,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = north]{card height};
    %\draw [step=.5, help lines] (0,0) grid (\cardwidth,\cardheight);



%begin card creation
        % draw card boundries and clip corners
        \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] \shapeCard;
          \clip[cardcorners] \shapeCard;

         % card image: placed first so other nodes will stack on top of this one
                              \tikzstyle{cardimage}=[ path picture={
                                                                        \node[below=-1.5mm] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\cardheight) {
                                                                        \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth cm]{#1}
                                                                        };
                                                                    } 
                                                            ]
                             \newcommand{\cardbackground}[1]{
                                    \draw[cardcorners, cardimage=#1] \shapeCard;
                                }
                             \cardbackground{ \cardimg }        


         % card type strip
        \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity = 5, color = black} ] \shapeLeftStripLong node[rotate = 90, above left, font=\LARGE] {  \color{white}\uppercase{ \cardtype }};

          % card icon strip
        \begin{scope}           
        \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity=5, color = black}  ] \shapeLeftStripShort node[ rotate=0,  above, yshift = -8.5, font = \LARGE ] at (0.5*\strippadding+0.5*\stripwidth, \titley){ \color{white}\uppercase{ \icon }};
        \end{scope}

         % card cost 
         \begin{scope}
            \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity=5, color = black}  ] \shapeRightStripShort node[ rotate=0, above, yshift = -8.5, font=\LARGE] 
            at  (\cardwidth - 0.5*\stripwidth - 1.5*\strippadding, \titley) 
            {  \color{white}\uppercase{ \cost }};
        \end{scope}

         % card title strip
            \fill[ color = black, opacity = .75, rounded corners=0.1cm  ] \shapeTitleArea node[ text width=3.75cm, rotate=0, font=\normalsize] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\titley) { \begin{center} \color{white!100}\uppercase{\normalsize \cardtitle }  \end{center} };

        % card content
            % card content: flavor text
                \node[below right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,0.5*\cardheight-\textpadding) { \textit{ \scriptsize \flavortext  } };

            %card content: card effect
                %line above text
                        \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5) -- (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5);     

                \node[below right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,3.5) {
                        \vspace{0.05cm}
                        {\normalsize \cardcontent }
                    };                      

        % card-ID
            %line above text
            \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4) -- (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4);     

            \node[above right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.05) {
                     \begin{flushright}  {\tiny \cardid }   \end{flushright} 
                       };               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[edit2] I want this on the back of the card....same code as before but without the fancy nodes and shapes

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

%debug grid and point locations
%   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=black!100, very thick](0, 0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = east]{ origin};
%   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width};
%   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width, card height};
%   \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=red!100, very thick](0,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = north]{card height};
    %\draw [step=.5, help lines] (0,0) grid (\cardwidth,\cardheight);



%begin card creation
        % draw card boundries and clip corners
        \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] \shapeCard;
          \clip[cardcorners] \shapeCard;

         % card image: placed first so other nodes will stack on top of this one
                              \tikzstyle{cardimage}=[ path picture={
                                                                        \node[below=-1.5mm] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\cardheight) {
                                                                        \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth cm]{#1}
                                                                        };
                                                                    } 
                                                            ]
                             \newcommand{\cardbackground}[1]{
                                    \draw[cardcorners, cardimage=#1] \shapeCard;
                                }
    %                        \cardbackground{ \cardimg }        


         % card type strip
%           \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity = 5, color = black} ] \shapeLeftStripLong node[rotate = 90, above left, font=\LARGE] {  \color{white}\uppercase{ \cardtype }};

          % card icon strip
%       \begin{scope}           
%       \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity=5, color = black}  ] \shapeLeftStripShort node[ rotate=0,  above, yshift = -8.5, font = \LARGE ] at (0.5*\strippadding+0.5*\stripwidth, \titley){ \color{white}\uppercase{ \icon }};
%       \end{scope}

         % card cost 
%        \begin{scope}
        %   \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity=5, color = black}  ] \shapeRightStripShort node[ rotate=0, above, yshift = -8.5, font=\LARGE] 
%           at  (\cardwidth - 0.5*\stripwidth - 1.5*\strippadding, \titley) 
%           {  \color{white}\uppercase{ \cost }};
%       \end{scope}

         % card title strip
        \fill[ color = black, opacity = .75, rounded corners=0.1cm  ] \shapeTitleArea node[ text width=3.75cm, rotate=0, font=\normalsize] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\titley) { \begin{center} \color{white!100}\uppercase{\normalsize \cardtitle }  \end{center} };

        % card content
            % card content: flavor text
        %       \node[below right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,0.5*\cardheight-\textpadding) { \textit{ \scriptsize \flavortext  } };

            %card content: card effect
                %line above text
            %           \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5) -- (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5);     

                \node[below right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,3.5) {
                        \vspace{0.05cm}
                        {\normalsize \cardcontent }
                    };                      

        % card-ID
            %line above text
    %       \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4) -- (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4);     

    %       \node[above right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.05) {
    %                \begin{flushright}  {\tiny \cardid }   \end{flushright} 
    %                  };               


         \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: cardface]

[image: card back example]

this is how I'd like to see a page...the outline of the 9 cards is present so each print will have 9 faces and on the other side of the paper you will have their respective 9 backs.  I was able to get the multiple card layouts but still not sure if this is the way to go considering the issues with attempting to get the back backs in the correct position.

[image: multicardlayout]

the code to get the multiple cards per page is here where i would create an actual function to call this script for me to keep the code cleaner than it currently is.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}

%debug grid and point locations
%   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=black!100, very thick](0, 0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = east]{ origin};
%   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width};
%   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width, card height};
%   \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=red!100, very thick](0,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = north]{card height};
    %\draw [step=.5, help lines] (0,0) grid (\cardwidth,\cardheight);



%begin card creation
        % draw card boundries and clip corners
        \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] \shapeCard;
        \begin{scope}

          \clip[cardcorners] \shapeCard;

         % card image: placed first so other nodes will stack on top of this one
                              \tikzstyle{cardimage}=[ path picture={
                                                                        \node[below=-1.5mm] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\cardheight) {
                                                                        \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth cm]{#1}
                                                                        };
                                                                    } 
                                                            ]
                             \newcommand{\cardbackground}[1]{
                                    \draw[cardcorners, cardimage=#1] \shapeCard;
                                }
                             \cardbackground{ \cardimg }        


         % card type strip
            \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity = 5, color = black} ] \shapeLeftStripLong node[rotate = 90, above left, font=\LARGE] {  \color{white}\uppercase{ \cardtype }};

          % card icon strip
        \begin{scope}           
        \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity=5, color = black}  ] \shapeLeftStripShort node[ rotate=0,  above, yshift = -8.5, font = \LARGE ] at (0.5*\strippadding+0.5*\stripwidth, \titley){ \color{white}\uppercase{ \icon }};
        \end{scope}

         % card cost 
         \begin{scope}
            \fill[red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, drop shadow = {opacity=5, color = black}  ] \shapeRightStripShort node[ rotate=0, above, yshift = -8.5, font=\LARGE] 
            at  (\cardwidth - 0.5*\stripwidth - 1.5*\strippadding, \titley) 
            {  \color{white}\uppercase{ \cost }};
        \end{scope}

         % card title strip
            \fill[ color = black, opacity = .75, rounded corners=0.1cm  ] \shapeTitleArea node[ text width=3.75cm, rotate=0, font=\normalsize] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\titley) { \begin{center} \color{white!100}\uppercase{\normalsize \cardtitle }  \end{center} };

        % card content
            % card content: flavor text
                \node[below right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,0.5*\cardheight-\textpadding) { \textit{ \scriptsize \flavortext  } };

            %card content: card effect
                %line above text
                        \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5) -- (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5);     

                \node[below right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,3.5) {
                        \vspace{0.05cm}
                        {\normalsize \cardcontent }
                    };                      

        % card-ID
            %line above text
            \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4) -- (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4);     

            \node[above right, text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.05) {
                     \begin{flushright}  {\tiny \cardid }   \end{flushright} 
                       };               

             \end{scope}



             % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
             % % card back

             \draw[lightgray,cardcorners]  ( \cardwidth+0.5,0) rectangle (2*\cardwidth, \cardheight);

             \draw[lightgray,cardcorners]  (2* \cardwidth+0.5,0) rectangle (3*\cardwidth, \cardheight);

         \end{tikzpicture}
         \\

            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{scope}
                      \clip[cardcorners] \shapeCard;
                        \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth, \cardheight);
                \end{scope}                  
                         \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] ( \cardwidth+0.5,0) rectangle (2*\cardwidth, \cardheight);

                         \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] (2* \cardwidth+0.5,0) rectangle (3*\cardwidth, \cardheight);

                     \end{tikzpicture}
         \\

            \begin{tikzpicture}

                                                \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] (0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth, \cardheight);

                                                 \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] ( \cardwidth+0.5,0) rectangle (2*\cardwidth, \cardheight);

                                                 \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] (2* \cardwidth+0.5,0) rectangle (3*\cardwidth, \cardheight);

                             \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: How should this card appear? Do you have some mock-up image? [For now, I see this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kdrJZ.png) (the grey A was added by me because I don't have the test.jpg image that you're loading in your code).

Comment: the image you generated is very close to what I have just having an actual image which i pulled from my library.  (not sure how to upload a pdf or screen shot).  As for the back I'm wanting to experiment with different ideas such as just a simple full image with a game name like you might see on a Magic The Gathering card, or even more complicated (for another project using similar methods) another card face but possibly with different shapes, nodes, text and format.  I figure if we could produce the same exact face for the flip side of the card, i could probably figure it out from there...

Comment: (continued) for the rest of the project.

Comment: sorry for inundating the post with comments: the final phase would be to have say 9 cards or 6 cards per a4paper to save on ... well the trees of course

Comment: If you have a screenshot in .png or .jpg format (maybe others are supported as well but these are always obvious), you can upload it in your question by clicking the small painting icon, which is next to the `{}` icon. Seeing your desired result would make it easier for me and possibly others to see what you want. :)

Comment: added pics....the desired effect is that the back of the card prints on the back of the face of the card.  like a flashcard.   I did look into the flashcard package but the tikz image seems to throw errors and i couldn't figure out the issues as i am new to both packages.

Comment: I thought this would be a simple issue with geometry and clever setting of the margins (i.e. an image on the far right of page 1 would have the reverse image (the back) on the far left of page 2....that is to say I expected a shift of the x-axis as page width minus the x1 and x2 coordinates of the image.  I tried that and the way LaTeX handles the image placement seems to allude me as each tikz image is its own environment with a reset of the axis.  I then tried a margin reset with new geometry and couldn't get the margins to actually change on the next page.

Comment: added the basic layout for the multi card print per page along with the rough code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LaTeX` considers every `tickpicture` like a character, so you only need to place corresponding front and back cards on same place at front and back sides of a page. `geometry` package can help to adjust margins for even and odd pages, and also for saving trees ;-)

In following code I've "cleaned" a little bit your code (much more can be done) and declared two new commands `\frontcard` and `\backcard`. Both have an optional parameter where all `\renewcommands` can be declared for defining card contents. I'm not satisfied with this solution, but I'll left as an exercise to find a better one.

With these commands, all cards can be arranged on a `\tabular` where front and back cards can be organized. The result looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, shadows, positioning}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage[hmargin=1mm,vmargin=5mm]{geometry}

\definecolor{titlebg}{rgb}{30, 30 , 30}

\newcommand{\icon}{$\alpha$}
\newcommand{\cardtype}{cardtype}
\newcommand{\cardtitle}{cardtitle}
\newcommand{\cost}{cost}
\newcommand{\flavortext}{flavortext}
\newcommand{\cardcontent}{cardcontent}
\newcommand{\cardid}{cardid}
\newcommand{\cardimg}{frog.jpg}

%   TikZ/PGF Settings für die Karten
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cardwidth}{6pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cardheight}{9pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\imagewidth}{\cardwidth*.9}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\imageheight}{0.75*\cardheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\stripwidth}{0.7pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\strippadding}{0.2pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\textpadding}{0.1pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\titley}{\cardheight-\strippadding-1.5*\textpadding-0.5*\stripwidth}

 %   Formen der einzelnen Kartenelemente/-bestandteile
\def\shapeCard{(0,0) rectangle (\cardwidth, \cardheight)}
\def\shapeLeftStripLong{(\strippadding,-0.2) rectangle 
    (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding-\strippadding-1)}
\def\shapeLeftStripShort{(\strippadding,\cardheight-\strippadding-1) rectangle 
    (\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight+0.2)}
\def\shapeRightStripShort{(\cardwidth-\stripwidth-\strippadding,
    \cardheight-\strippadding-1) rectangle (\cardwidth-\strippadding,   
    \cardheight+0.2)}
\def\shapeTitleArea{(2*\strippadding+\stripwidth,\cardheight-\strippadding) 
    rectangle (\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth,\cardheight-2*\stripwidth)}
\def\shapeContentArea{(2*\strippadding+\stripwidth,0.5*\cardheight) rectangle 
    (\cardwidth+0.2,-0.2)}

\tikzset{%
    cardcorners/.style={rounded corners=0.25cm},
    cardimage/.style={path picture={
         \node[below=-1.5mm] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\cardheight) {
             \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth cm]{#1}};}},
    strips/.style={red!100, rounded corners=0.1cm, 
         drop shadow={opacity=1,color=black}},
    strip font/.style={font=\LARGE, text=white}
}

\newcommand{\cardbackground}[1]{
    \draw[cardcorners, cardimage=#1] \shapeCard;}

\newcommand{\frontcard}[1][]{#1
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%debug grid and point locations
%    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=black!100, very thick](0, 0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = east]{ origin};
%    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,0) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width};
%    \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!100, very thick](6,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = west]{card width, card height};
%    \filldraw[color=black!60, fill=red!100, very thick](0,9) circle (0.1) node[color = black!100, anchor = north]{card height};
%    %\draw [step=.5, help lines] (0,0) grid (\cardwidth,\cardheight);

%begin card creation
    % draw card boundries and clip corners
     \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] \shapeCard;
     \clip[cardcorners] \shapeCard;

     % card image: placed first so other nodes will stack on top of this one
     \cardbackground{\cardimg}        

     % card type strip
     \fill[strips] \shapeLeftStripLong node[rotate = 90, above left, strip font] 
         {\uppercase{\cardtype}};

     % card icon strip
%     \begin{scope}           
        \fill[strips] \shapeLeftStripShort node[rotate=0, above, yshift=-8.5, 
            strip font] at (0.5*\strippadding+0.5*\stripwidth, \titley)
                {\uppercase{ \icon }};
%     \end{scope}

     % card cost 
%     \begin{scope}
         \fill[strips] \shapeRightStripShort node[rotate=0, above, yshift=-8.5,
             strip font] 
             at  (\cardwidth - 0.5*\stripwidth - 1.5*\strippadding, \titley) 
             {\uppercase{ \cost }};
%     \end{scope}

     % card title strip
     \fill[color = black, opacity = .75, rounded corners=0.1cm] 
         \shapeTitleArea node[text width=3.75cm, font=\normalsize, 
         text=white, align=center] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\titley) 
         {\uppercase{\cardtitle}};

     % card content
     % card content: flavor text
     \node[below right, font=\itshape\scriptsize,
     text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] 
     at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,0.5*\cardheight-\textpadding) 
     {\flavortext};

     %card content: card effect
     %line above text
     \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5) --
         (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 3.5);     

     \node[below right, font=\normalsize,
     text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] 
     at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,3.5) 
     {\vspace{0.05cm}{ \cardcontent }};                      

     % card-ID
     %line above text
     \draw[ultra thin, <->] (25*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4) -- 
         (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.4);     

     \node[above right, font=\tiny, align=right,
     text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] 
     at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding, 0.05) 
     { \cardid };               
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\backcard}[1][]{#1
\begin{tikzpicture}
%begin card creation
    % draw card boundries and clip corners
    \draw[lightgray,cardcorners] \shapeCard;
    \clip[cardcorners] \shapeCard;

     % card title strip
     \fill[color = black, opacity = .75, rounded corners=0.1cm] 
         \shapeTitleArea node[text width=3.75cm, font=\normalsize, 
         text=white, align=center] at (0.5*\cardwidth,\titley) 
         {\uppercase{\cardtitle}};

     \node[below right, font=\normalsize,
     text width=(\cardwidth-2*\strippadding-\stripwidth-2*\textpadding-0.3)*1cm] 
     at (2*\strippadding+\stripwidth+\textpadding,3.5) 
     {\vspace{0.05cm}{ \cardcontent }};                      

\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 1}] &
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 2}] &
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 3}] \\
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 4}] &
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 5}] &
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 6}] \\
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 7}] &
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 8}] &
\frontcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 9}] 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 3}] &
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 2}] &
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 1}] \\
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 6}] &
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 5}] &
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 4}] \\
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 9}] &
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 8}] &
\backcard[\renewcommand{\cardcontent}{\LARGE 7}] 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks for the assist.  The only thing that seems to be the issue now (and I suspect its the printer) is that the vertical margins are not perfectly aligned...that is the x positioning of the card-face and card-back are correct but the card-back is just slightly (maybe 10-20pts?) lower than the face.  I think I can take it from here with some y-shifts or margin adjustments to fit my printer.  Otherwise, this is VERY helpful.  I'll clean it up, make it more efficient, and then post back the final version for folks to use.  Thank You Again!

Comment: @william glad to help you. Something you can clean a little bit: red strips. You draw them as rectangles and later on put a node to write their contents. I think it's better to use adjusted nodes like in cardcontents.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  This project has been fun not just in the game creation phase of the actual game but the learning Tikz package as well.  I love LaTeX and there is sooo much to do with it.  I'll be cleaning this up over the weekend and post the final version I end up using.  With luck, some others will find use in this post/thread.

Comment: okay so now I feel really silly.  I've attempted to play with all sorts of margins, alignments, and flushleft/right calls etc to get the back and the face of the cards to line up in both tabular and non tabular environments (non tab being done with a single card).  I am not able to get the front and back faces to align perfectly...the y axis does (I misspoke earlier when I said the x axis did) however the x axis is just slightly off even with

Comment: ...off even with <pre> \usepackage[outer = 0.5in, inner = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in]{geometry} </pre>...which I figured would make all the margins equal...help?  I guess what I'm asking is were you able to print this on a printer and it work for you?  or does your printer also have a slight x-axis shift?

Comment: So just discovered the layout package. Looks like there's some padding I didn't know about. I think I can handle this from here.

Comment: **Note**: `\definecolor{titlebg}{rgb}{30, 30 , 30}` is the same as `\definecolor{titlebg}{rgb}{30, 30 , 30}`, with `rgb` the range is 0..1 so 30 gets truncated to 1 = white.